# Extract variable declarations from JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to create a variable name exchanger. Simple iterating over lines from a JavaScript file and exchange every variable name with a random name from a dictionary i can supply.

I can do that so far, but i am stuck optimizing the search regex for variable keywords.

I first define Keywords which i am looking for:

```
const VARIABLE_KEYWORDS = ["var", "let", "const"];
```

Then i iterate over every line from the input file and extract the variable names and store them in an array. Once i have all variable names stored, i make them unique and then simply replace them in the original file with a random word.

That is my extractVariables(line) logic, where the variable line is a string:

```
function extractVariables(line) {
  let lineCnt = 1;
  let found_vars = [];

  // if the line is not empty, parse it
  if (line.trim().length !== 0) {    
    // find a variable keyword
    for (let key of VARIABLE_KEYWORDS) {
      // regex to match the variable keyword and its not inside a string definition \"|\' , and is not used as a property name |\.
      var re = new RegExp("(?<!\"|\')\\b" + key + "\\b(?!\"|\')", "g");

      // while there are variables declared in the line, add them to the variables array
      while ((match = re.exec(line)) != null) {

        const indexOfKeyword = match.index + key.length;

        // get the name after and store it in an array
        if (indexOfKeyword > 0) { 
          let found_var = line.substr(indexOfKeyword).trim().split(' ').shift();
          // if a keyword is found, but no variable defined afterwards do not break everything
          if(found_var.length !== 0){
            found_vars.push(found_var);    
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return found_vars;
}
```

My regex is missing some fixes.

```
new RegExp("(?<!\"|\')\\b" + key + "\\b(?!\"|\')", "g");
```

1. The lookbehind is not supported.
2. KEYWORDS inside a String like "foo var let me be" are still found, i only fixed it if they are the only word next to a " or '
3. Scopes {} are ignored

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: what if the variable statement is `var a, b, c=10`? Use http://esprima.org/

Comment: You need to use a parsing engine, not regex.

Comment: True, multi declarations in one line with one keyword would be ignored as well. What parsing engine to take for such a problem. Esprima looks very promising.

Comment: [This looks like what you need?](https://esprima.readthedocs.io/en/4.0/syntactic-analysis.html#token-collection)  At least as a starting point, perhaps.

Comment: I have tested it and although it kind of does extract the identifiers, it produces errors on the plainest things. Empty lines, backslash, syntax errors etc. I don't want to have the file to be syntactically correct. It should just identify keywords inside a string.

Comment: @AHahn, thank you! This is the perfect solution for me.